# Transforing C# list into hierarchical tree

Tags: c#, json, data-structures, tree, json.net

I have a C# list which contains name of file and the folder under which that file is available.

```
public class Data
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Folder { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tree
    {
        public List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>();


        public Tree()
        {
            Data d = new Data();
            d.Name = "FireFox";
            d.Folder = @"Testing\Mac OSX";
            dataList.Add(d);

            d = new Data();
            d.Name = "Safari";
            d.Folder = @"Testing\Mac OSX";
            dataList.Add(d);

            d = new Data();
            d.Name = "Chrome";
            d.Folder = @"Testing\Mac OSX";
            dataList.Add(d);

            d = new Data();
            d.Name = "FireFox";
            d.Folder = @"Testing\Windows";
            dataList.Add(d);

            d = new Data();
            d.Name = "Safari";
            d.Folder = @"Testing\Windows";
            dataList.Add(d);

            d = new Data();
            d.Name = "Chrome";
            d.Folder = @"Testing\Windows";
            dataList.Add(d);

            d = new Data();
            d.Name = "Internet Exploder";
            d.Folder = @"Testing\Windows";
            dataList.Add(d);


            d = new Data();
            d.Name = "Chrome";
            d.Folder = @"Testing\Linux";
            dataList.Add(d);

            d = new Data();
            d.Name = "Firefox";
            d.Folder = @"Testing\Linux";
            dataList.Add(d);

            d = new Data();
            d.Name = "Testing First Child";
            d.Folder = @"Testing";
            dataList.Add(d);

            d = new Data();
            d.Name = "First Child";
            d.Folder = null;
            dataList.Add(d);

        }

    }
```

I need to convert this list into hierarchical json object. The output should look like this:

```
{
            "text": ".",
            children: [{
                task: 'First Child',
                duration: 6.5,
                user: 'Tommy Maintz',
                leaf: true,
                iconCls: 'task'

            }, {
                task: 'Testing',
                duration: 2,
                user: 'Core Team',
                iconCls: 'task-folder',
                children: [{
                    task: 'Testing First Child',
                    duration: 6.5,
                    user: 'Tommy',
                    leaf: true,
                    iconCls: 'task'

                }, {
                    task: 'Mac OSX',
                    duration: 0.75,
                    user: 'Tommy Maintz',
                    iconCls: 'task-folder',
                    children: [{
                        task: 'FireFox',
                        duration: 0.25,
                        user: 'Tommy Maintz',
                        iconCls: 'task',
                        leaf: true
                    }, {
                        task: 'Safari',
                        duration: 0.25,
                        user: 'Tommy Maintz',
                        iconCls: 'task',
                        leaf: true
                    }, {
                        task: 'Chrome',
                        duration: 0.25,
                        user: 'Tommy Maintz',
                        iconCls: 'task',
                        leaf: true
                    }]
                }, {
                    task: 'Windows',
                    duration: 3.75,
                    user: 'Darrell Meyer',
                    iconCls: 'task-folder',
                    children: [{
                        task: 'FireFox',
                        duration: 0.25,
                        user: 'Darrell Meyer',
                        iconCls: 'task',
                        leaf: true
                    }, {
                        task: 'Safari',
                        duration: 0.25,
                        user: 'Darrell Meyer',
                        iconCls: 'task',
                        leaf: true
                    }, {
                        task: 'Chrome',
                        duration: 0.25,
                        user: 'Darrell Meyer',
                        iconCls: 'task',
                        leaf: true
                    }, {
                        task: 'Internet Exploder',
                        duration: 3,
                        user: 'Darrell Meyer',
                        iconCls: 'task',
                        leaf: true
                    }]
                }, {
                    task: 'Linux',
                    duration: 0.5,
                    user: 'Aaron Conran',
                    iconCls: 'task-folder',
                    children: [{
                        task: 'FireFox',
                        duration: 0.25,
                        user: 'Aaron Conran',
                        iconCls: 'task',
                        leaf: true
                    }, {
                        task: 'Chrome',
                        duration: 0.25,
                        user: 'Aaron Conran',
                        iconCls: 'task',
                        leaf: true
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }
```

What I am trying do is:

1. Loop over every item in the dataList
2. Lets take first object in our example `Folder Path : Testing\Mac OSX`
3. If the path does not exists create a new json node and add it
4. So the system will create two nodes First for "Testing"  and under it "Mac OSX"
5. Now Add the file name FireFox Mac OSX
6. If the node exists just add the file name under that node.
7. Repeat this for all items

*Is it possible to achieve this using JSON.NET library or any other library??*

Thanks

Comment: I really doubt JSON.NET could turn a flat structure into a hierarchical one since it's supposed to be just a serializer... So, first you need to turn your flat .net structure into a hierarchical one and then serialize it...

Comment: @digEmAll: What i meant is, using JSON.net, first create a node and the add child nodes to it. In this case, first check if a node with name Testing exists or not, if not then add the node. Now we will check if a node by the name Mac OSX exists under the testing node or not. For us to do that we first need to search testing node. once we find that node we will add Mac OSX under it as child node. So does JSON.NET provide node searching capabilities & the ability to add node under another node

Comment: @Brownn_Dynamite, This isn't really a JSON question, it is a transformation question.  JSON isn't for transforming lists, etc, like dig said, it is for reading/writing.

Comment: This question is a duplicate (with added information) of [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20399474/56778). Please delete the other question.

Comment: @JimMischel: Though fundamentally the questions are same, the other question has lot more information & has more code. I thought it would be difficult for people to follow it and that is why I created this new question.

Comment: Normally you would edit the question rather than post a new one. If that other question has information you think is pertinent, add it to this question. but delete the other, as there is no need for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we can achieve the result

```
class Node
{
    public Node()
    {
        Children = new List<Node>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
}


Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("Kitchen supplies", "Shopping / Housewares");
dict.Add("Groceries", "Shopping / Housewares");
dict.Add("Cleaning supplies", "Shopping / Housewares");
dict.Add("Office supplies", "Shopping / Housewares");
dict.Add("Retile kitchen", "Shopping / Remodeling");
dict.Add("Ceiling", "Shopping / Remodeling / Paint bedroom");
dict.Add("Walls", "Shopping / Remodeling / Paint bedroom");
dict.Add("Misc", null);
dict.Add("Other", "Shopping / Remodeling");

Node root = new Node();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
{
    Node parent = root;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Value))
    {
        Node child = null;
        foreach (string part in kvp.Value.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            string name = part.Trim();
            child = parent.Children.Find(n => n.Name == name);
            if (child == null)
            {
                child = new Node { Name = name };
                parent.Children.Add(child);
            }
            parent = child;
        }
    }
    parent.Children.Add(new Node { Name = kvp.Key });
}

//Using JSON.NET
 string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
```

Answer (score 0):

Translate your structure into the following structure and that should be able to be serialized into the Json structure you are after.

```
 public class Child
        {
            public string task { get; set; }
            public double duration { get; set; }
            public string user { get; set; }
            public bool leaf { get; set; }
            public string iconCls { get; set; }
            public List<Child> children { get; set; }
        }

        public class Tree
        {
            public string text { get; set; }
            public List<Child> children { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: I think he is looking for something to un-flatten his source list.

Comment: There are few challenges: How can I create nodes for folders and sub folder. Two folder at different levels can have same name, how can I ensure that files are added under correct node. What is the most effective technique. I can achieve the result after several rounds of transformation but i want to use the best technique.